# How to run Monkeyrunner script on multiple devices at the same time

Tags: android, python, monkeyrunner

I am trying to run a monkeyrunner script on multiple devices to do some basic operations.I figured out that initialy I will start of writing a script to perform basic action in two connected devices.

```
  from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

  import time

   import sys


    import time


   devices = os.popen('adb devices').read().strip().split('\n')[1:]

 device1 = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection( devices[0].split('\t')[0])  
  package = 'com.android.browser'

  activity = 'com.android.browser.BrowserActivity'
  runComponent = package + '/' + activity
 device1.startActivity(component=runComponent)

  MonkeyRunner.sleep(1)

 device2 = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection( devices[1].split('\t')[0])  
  package = 'com.android.browser'

 activity = 'com.android.browser.BrowserActivity'
 runComponent = package + '/' + activity
  device2.startActivity(component=runComponent)
```

When i run this script, it never finish executing. The browser action happen on one of the connected device but not on other. Can you guys help me fix this or if you have a better code(ideas) to run an activity on multiple devices, Please do let me know~ I am newbie and completely new to the programming world!Thanks in advance

Comment: Elsa, I think should be done differently.
Divide the script into two parts. One will run a test it is a single device. Another part of the first script to run on multiple devices.

Comment: Can you advise me how to make it separate?

Comment: bash, python or java... Now our group is developing such a service.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51253369/monkeyrunner-connect-to-multiple-devices-at-the-same-time/51298641#51298641

Answer (score 2):

you can give like

> ```
> device1 = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection('', devices[0].split('\t')[0])
> ```

this will help

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it is to write a script that explicitly binds to the devices. The link below shows how for emulators

http://chanakaudaya.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/monkeyrunner-tutorial-running-tests-on-multiple-devices-with-monkeyrunner-13/

also seems similar to this question(Which i answered):

[Can not simultaneously run monkeyrunner scripts (e.g. two monkeyrunner process) on multi device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231856/can-not-simultaneously-run-monkeyrunner-scripts-e-g-two-monkeyrunner-process/13460438#13460438)