# Can not simultaneously run monkeyrunner scripts (e.g. two monkeyrunner process) on multi device

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

test.py script content:

```
import ....

device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(10,sys.argv[1])

device.startActivity(component='package/activity')

'''
some monkeyrunner events
'''
```

I have two device , labled device1-id and device2-id

1. run the monkeyrunner test.py device1-id &
2. run the monkeyrunner test.py device2-id &

I found some events in device2-id were sent to device1-id.  I don't know why ?

I noticed some tutorials , they said , if run monkeyrunner on more devices, could write the script like below:

```
device1 = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(10,device1-id)
device2 = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(10,device2-id)

device1.actions

device2.actions
```

but this wasn't what I need.  Anybody know why the monkeyrunner behaves this ?

What I need is that , I have one script , would run the same script on multi device simultaneously .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Monkeyrunner is not thread safe.

To test this, create 2 scripts, hardcoding the deviceId into each.
Start each script:
In windows, use the "start script1" and then "start script2"
In Unix use "script1 &; script2 &"

Notice that script1 fails with errors after it looks like it started working just fine. and that SCript2 also fails to do what it was intended to do because it gets commands from both windows.

Comment: I never thought of that before.  Do you get any materials about non-thread-safe of monkeyrunner ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the monkey port so you may want to use a command line argument like so

```
 # Imports the monkeyrunner modules used by this program
 from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
 import sys

 # Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object
 device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(timeOut,"emulator-"+ sys.argv[1])

 MONKEYRunner Actions . . . .
```

NOTE: sys.arv[0] is always the test file

Call by entering the following on the command line:

```
   monkeyrunner test.py PortNumber
```

Comment: Thank rytan,  sorry I'm saying not clearly.  you told me to define a var in the script , and make the script could be re-used in running test.    what I want to know , is that ,  actually at the same I run two same monkeyrunner script on two devices or emulators ,  I found some key events in device2 were sent to device1-id. I don't know why ?

Comment: The reason for the argument is that monkey runner is ran using tcp/ip without it I had commands getting sent to the wrong emulator. i had to make sure it only sends commands to the specified "client". I have one script running on 3 emulators at the exact same time, the only change is the emulator they are running on has a different port.

Comment: sorry to reply lately. In my just thinking ,  I thought,  2 device connected to the pc , then should two different port for each device(emulator) .  And the serial number ("adb devices" prints) will point to the specified device.  So in my scripts, I just pass the serial number to the arguments. I think It's no different between your sciprt and mine.   Reallly not work in my scripts, I need to dig more deeply.

Comment: The devices will have different port number in my case i start two different emulator that are clone of an original. for Example one is Tester5554 and Tester5556. The problem is that monkeyrunner needs to know which emulator to talk to. Here is an article to show the emaple i followed  http://chanakaudaya.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/monkeyrunner-tutorial-running-tests-on-multiple-devices-with-monkeyrunner-13/

Comment: also note that it is better to try multi device as emulators as the deveice number is always the "emultor-"port