# Monkeyrunner. Connect to multiple devices at the same time

Tags: monkeyrunner

I used this script to connect to multiple Android devices at the same time (i.e. to send files via adb):

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
import time
import sys
import time
import os

devices = os.popen('adb devices').read().strip().split('\n')[1:]
device1 = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection( devices[0].split('\t')[0])  
package = 'com.android.browser'
activity = 'com.android.browser.BrowserActivity'
runComponent = package + '/' + activity
device1.startActivity(component=runComponent)

MonkeyRunner.sleep(1)
device2 = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection( devices[1].split('\t')[0])  
package = 'com.android.browser'

activity = 'com.android.browser.BrowserActivity'
runComponent = package + '/' + activity
device2.startActivity(component=runComponent)
```

I used

```
adb 1.0.36 (Rev 1:7.0.0+r33-2) and
monkyrunner(Jython 2.5.3 (2.5:c56500f08d34+, Aug 13 2012, 14:54:35)
```

But all I get is:

```
09:02:54 E/DeviceMonitor: Adb connection Error:EOF                                                                                                                                                                               
09:02:54 E/DeviceMonitor: Connection attempts: 1                                                                                                                                                                                 
09:02:55 E/DeviceMonitor: Connection attempts: 2                                                                                                                                                                                 
09:02:56 E/DeviceMonitor: Connection attempts: 3
```

Any hints what to do?

Thanks!

(Original Thread: [How to run Monkeyrunner script on multiple devices at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652910/how-to-run-monkeyrunner-script-on-multiple-devices-at-the-same-time) )

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which supports multiple devices. If I recall correctly, this was one of the limitations of `monkeyrunner` that AndroidViewClient solved.

You can simply generate the script using

```
$ culebra -Uu --multi-device --start-activity='com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main' -o multi-browser.py
```

which generates a unit test (`-U`), does not verify what's in the screen dump (`-u`), use multiple devices, starts a specific activity as a precondition and saves the generated script to `multi-device.py`.

Then, run the script as

```
$ multi-browser.py -s all
```

where `-s` specifies the serial numbers of the devices where you want the script to run, `all` in this case, and the browser will start on all of them.